# How to limit the amount of asset that someone can have in 1 wallet?

Tags: blockchain, smartcontracts, wavesplatform, ride

I'm trying to create a smart asset that limits every amount of assets a portfolio can have, suppose I created Age Coin (fictitious and unofficial name) and want every portfolio to have only 100 assets. The goal is to disrupt large speculators who manipulate the market.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I recommend you to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and rephrase your question here.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily check asset balance and deny transactions if `current amount + incoming amount > 100`

Full asset script can look like below:

```
{-# STDLIB_VERSION 2 #-}
{-# CONTENT_TYPE EXPRESSION #-}
{-# SCRIPT_TYPE ASSET #-}


match (tx) {
    case t:TransferTransaction => {
        let currentBalance = assetBalance(t.recipient, t.assetId)
        currentBalance + t.amount <= 100
    }
    case _ => false
}
```

Comment: Well, I think there's a problem with your script. It does not allow the distribution of tokens, since the creator ends up having more tokens than allowed. So, could this be done in a logic where the one who has more tokens than allowed can send but can not receive?